# pass commands to the webBrowser through Android app

Tags: android

I have two buttons ON and OFF in my android app.

what i want is onClick of ON Button I just want to hit **myIpaddress/On** in browser and immediately come back to my app and simillarly for OFF button(**myIpaddress/Off**) and return to app.

I searched a lot.what I have found is

```
    String url = "http://myIpaddress/On";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
```

but with this i cant come back to my app means web browser remains open, i don't want that. I just want to hit that IP address and return back to my UI

How to acheive this???
 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an HTTP request not open a full web browser.

[Look into the Volley library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html), other networking library, or write an `AsyncTask`

Comment: can you provide some links for explanation??

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue in different way

used WebView to hit url and made its visibility gone

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Press"
    android:id="@+id/webView"></WebView>
```

then on button click hit the url in this way

```
webView.loadUrl("myIPAddress/on");
```